# Is Strong MAC stronger than existential unforgeability?

Tags: mac, authenticated-encryption

Especially in the context of Encrypt-then-Authenticate.

Comment: [Strong Mac?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237061762_Strong_Message_Authentication_and_Confidentiality_Checking_Approach_through_Authentication_Code_Tied_to_Ciphertext)

Comment: Can you please link the paper / resource where a "strong MAC" is mentioned / defined?

Comment: Do you mean strong existential unforgeability vs. existential unforgeability?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that by a "strong MAC" you mean that it is infeasible for an adversary to also find a different MAC tag on a message which has been tagged. Any deterministic MAC (with canonical verification) is a strong MAC, but it is certainly *not* the case that every MAC is a strong MAC. Thus, indeed, there exist secure MAC schemes (that are existentially unforgeable) but are not strong MACs, meaning that this is a strictly stronger notion (by definition, a strong MAC is existentially unforgeable so the question is just whether it's the same or strictly stronger as a notion). Note that in order to achieve CCA security you need a strong MAC and thus in the context of encrypt-then-authenticate, this is indeed needed. It is possible to define a weaker type of authenticated channel for which it would not be necessary, but typically it is required.

For those not sure what a strong MAC is, see the following pasted excerpt from "Introduction to Modern Cryptography":

[image: strong MAC excerpt]

Comment: I see, thanks! I asked this question as I believed existential unforgeability would be sufficient in authenticated encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes; in the second edition.