# Are there any non Canonical Verifiable Cryptographic MACs

Tags: mac

In the 2. edition of the Modern Introduction to Cryptography, by Katz and Lindell, there is a definition for MACs;

> **Canonical verification.** For deterministic message authentication codes
>   (that is, where $\text{Mac}$ is a deterministic algorithm), the canonical way to perform verification is to simply re-compute the tag and check for equality. In other words, $\operatorname{Vrfy}_k(m, t)$ first computes $\tilde{t} := \text{Mac}_k (m)$ and then outputs $1$ if and only if $\tilde{t} = t$.

Then, later

> It is not hard to see that if a secure MAC uses canonical verification then it is also [strongly secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63347/61539). This is important since all real-world MACs use canonical verification.

All of the cryptographic MACs, that I know, use canonical verification.

- Is there any non Canonical Verifiable Cryptographic MACs?
- If not, then this definition is redundant, or is this definition is defined for future MAC schemes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Message Authentication, Revisited](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/059). This paper presents MACs with different properties, and in order to achieve these properties randomization is used. Since the MACs are probabilistic, the verification cannot be canonical.

Comment: It's not a "problem", but a potential property. Indeed, any deterministic MAC has canonical verification in practice (you can build one that doesn't but there's no reason to).